# Opening/Changing a Iframe using a click event in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

On my WordPress website, I have a menu down one side and a embedded prezzie within an `IFrame` next to the menu.

I want to use some form of click event to change the content of the `IFrame` to another prezie without the page being refreshed, to give it a seamless change but I am stuck on how to write the code.

The menu buttons are actually pictures trapped in a map, to give the illusion they are actually functional buttons.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to click somewhere and replace your iframe with other content without refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a JavaScript function to swap the Url of the Prezi iframe.

```
function changePrezi (preziKey) {
  var url = "http://prezi.com/embed/" + preziKey + "/";      
  document.getElementById('prezi').src = url;
}
```

Then add `onClick` handlers to your menu links/buttons to call the `changePrezi` function, passing in the proper Prezi key.

```
<button onClick="changePrezi('ltv92t40up8k')">Prezi 1</button>
<button onClick="changePrezi('rqqnh_taqx1l')">Prezi 2</button>
<iframe id="prezi" frameborder="0" width="550" height="400"></iframe>
```

Here is a [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/L8OfRBpvuNhK1l9f2l4n?p=preview).